# Quadratic Programming in C# / .NET

Tags: c#, .net, scientific-computing, mathematical-optimization

Does anyone know of a free package that will solve quadratic programming problems in C#?

I've googled and found a few.  But it's hard to tell which is the best and fastest. Does anyone have a favorite?

Comment: Can you give us the links to the packages you found?

Comment: I guess I might simply not know the terminology, but I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "quadratic programming". Are you looking for something related to quadratic curves (e.g. ellipses, hyperbolae, etc.) or for something related to second-degree equations (quadratic equation, second-degree differential equations) or something else?

Comment: @Mehrdad QP is a branch of mathematical programming (multidimentional optimization) where the target function f(x) is quadratic and constraints are linear.

Comment: @mishau: Ah... so I'm guessing they're related to lagrange multipliers, eigenvalues, etc.? Does linear algebra work for them?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I think in our case a special library needs to be used. In C# I mean.

Comment: Since there are a variety of algorithms (for linear programming at least), I'm betting "fastest" depends on the particular model you're solving.  You might need to try a few and see how they pan out if you are interested in which is fastest for your cases.

Comment: Do you know any with quadratic constraints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ALGLIB](http://www.alglib.net/) is a great library with both free (GPL) and commercial licenses available. It has good documentation and offers a number of optimization algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the MS Solver Foundations?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/hh145003

Answer (score 1):

I have found: [Accord.NET](http://accord-framework.net/) (LGPL).

It is [documented](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Math_Optimization_GoldfarbIdnaniQuadraticSolver.htm) and with [an example app](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/tree/master/Samples/Math/Solver).

Answer (score 0):

CenterSpace Software has very fast C# quadratic programming classes in their commercial NMath libraries.

Here is some example code: http://www.centerspace.net/examples/nmath/csharp/analysis/quadratic-programming-example.php

Best,

Paul

CenterSpace Software